# Setup InstallShield Limited Edition for VS2010 so it automatically uninstalls previous versions of my application

Tags: upgrade, uninstallation, installshield-le

I am working on a WPF desktop application and I am deploying through an install file generated by InstallShield Limited Edition.
I would like the installer to prompt the user and remove any previous versions of the application before installing the new version.
I suspect this is done via the Upgrade Paths option in InstallShield, but I can't get it figured out.

Answer goes to an explanation or a link to a decent how-to, tutorial or manual page that answers my question.

At the moment, when running the installer, I get:
"Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel."

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

- in Solution Explorer go to "General Information" page
- increase the Product Version
- generate a new Product Code
- make sure that ALLUSERS property has the same value as in the old package
- go to "Upgrade Paths" page and add the old MSI
- build and install your new version

When running this new package it should automatically detect and remove older versions.

You can read about Windows Installer upgrades here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Hi Cosmis. I have since noticed that this solution simply installs multiple versions of the application - changing the Product Code means Windows sees it as an entirely different application, and it has no link to the previously installed version. I have not been able to get this to work yet, but I'm pretty sure generating a new Product Code is not the way to go. Soz.

Comment: Each new version should have a different Product Code. The versions are linked through Upgrade Code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372399(VS.85).aspx?ppud=4

Comment: Have you tested this? Because I've created a Hello World like app to test it with, and generating a new Product Code causes Windows to install the new version alongside the old version - the Add Remove Programs list shows both versions. Worse - my desktop shortcut still runs the old version. If you have tested this and get a different results, then perhaps some implementation changed? I am using VS2010, InstallShield LE, and Windows 7.

Comment: Also, from http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/MajorMinorSmall.htm: "ProductCode—This is a Windows Installer property that contains the GUID of a product. Windows Installer treats two products with different ProductCode GUIDs as unrelated, even if the values for the ProductName property are the same."

Comment: You didn't read the full article. At the bottom there is a table with what needs to change for each upgrade type. For a major upgrade you need to change the Product Version and Product Code and keep the same Upgrade Code. This is also explained in the article I mentioned in my post. I edited my post to include some more suggestions.

Comment: The combination of a new Product Code AND the Upgrade Path solved the problem. It works! I nearly collapsed with joy. Thanks for your patience.