# How do I get InstallShield to apply an update (replace version 6.0 with 6.1)?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield

I have upgraded a shipping Windows Desktop application from version 6.0.15.0 to version 6.1.0.0.  I am using the Limited Edition of InstallShield, with Visual Studio 2013, for the installation program.  Upon running the installation program on a PC that has version 6.0.15.0 installed, the installation program says "Another Version of this product is already installed"

I set the Product Version to "6.1.0.0." in the upgraded version. I did not change the product code or the upgrade code GUIDs (from version 6.0), because the documentations says not to change them.  The documentation says,

"Because the product code uniquely identifies your product, changing the code after distributing a release of your product is not recommended."

"The upgrade code, stored in the UpgradeCode property, should remain the same for all versions of a product."

What must be changed in the InstallShield Visual Studio project to enable it to replace 6.0 with 6.1, without a need to uninstall the previous version (6.0) of the program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setup InstallShield Limited Edition for VS2010 so it automatically uninstalls previous versions of my application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414143/setup-installshield-limited-edition-for-vs2010-so-it-automatically-uninstalls-pr)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do do this. 
Assuming you want a major upgrade ( deploy everything again),  you just need to go to the upgrades and right click,  add major upgrade.
Once you have the major upgrade,  you can choose any previous version.